# GoogleSheet: Insert Image Based on Cell Value and File Name

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a **GoogleScript** which can automatically insert the image in the cell based on File Name. The steps are below:

1. Get Name (in Column A)
2. Lookup the image file in "Image Folder"
3. Insert the image with fixed size (Column B)

I am attaching the sheet for your understanding.

- [GDoc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chLNGbmROiPu57wxibNooyreGcnGnS9pyBFM5ZDRTdI/edit#gid=110715797)
- [Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AV5pTs3l7GGMNH7-C8rixjcWNNTsmbpE?usp=sharing)

Script that I use but is not working:

```js
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {
    //writes the headers for the spreadsheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(["Image"]);
    var folderId = "1AV5pTs3l7GGMNH7-C8rixjcWNNTsmbpE";
    
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var contents = folder.getFiles();
    
    var cnt = 0;
    var file;
    
    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        cnt++;
    
        Logger.log(file);
        Logger.log(cnt);
        // writes the various chunks to the spreadsheet- just delete anything you don't want
            data = [
    
                "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
                file.getDescription(),
                "=image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() +"\")",
            ];
    
            sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
};
```

Comment: When I saw your container-bound script of shared Spreadsheet, I noticed that there are 2 same function names of `listFilesInFolder`. Please rename one of  `listFilesInFolder` function and test it again. Because when I tested your script, no error occurs and your goal can be achieved. Although I'm not sure about the detail of `Script That I use but NOT WORKING`, I thought that this might be the reason of your issue of it.